# RandomForest Weights error no attribute copy

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was trying out the random forest classifier algorithm and when using weights while fitting the trees, I get this error:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1)
rf.fit(train, target, my_weights)
```

CONSOLE:

```
line 86, in _parallel_build_trees

curr_sample_weight = sample_weight.copy()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
    dataset = genfromtxt(open('data/training_edited.csv','r'), delimiter=',',dtype=float)[1:]
    print("Reading training.csv")
    target = [x[32] for x in dataset]
    my_weights = [x[31] for x in dataset]
    train = [x[1:31] for x in dataset]
```

Comment: sample_weight is list right?

Comment: what are `train, target, my_weights`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

instead of `curr_sample_weight = sample_weight.copy()`

```
curr_sample_weight = sample_weight[:]
```

to copy list try above line

use copy.copy():

```
import copy
curr_sample_weight = copy.copy(sample_weight)
```

Comment: Thanks I had to change it inside scikit lib forest.py library I think it´s broken somehow.

Comment: Using numpy ndarrays as input should suffice. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide `np.ndarray`s as input, at least for `sample_weight`, but ideally for all input:

Change what you have to

```
import numpy as np
target = np.array([x[32] for x in dataset])  # dataset[:, 32]
my_weights = np.array([x[31] for x in dataset])  # dataset[:, 31]
train = np.array([x[1:31] for x in dataset])  # dataset[:, 1:31]
```

This can probably even be done more elegantly, since `dataset` will itself (probably) already be an array (if file homogeneous), see commented code as suggestions.